# How to set an alias upon command execution?

Tags: bash, shell-script, alias, command-history, command-substitution

I want other developers to have some convenient methods. Therefore I want to give them a script, that automatically sets an alias.

E.g the command `grunt compileModule:[modulename]` should set the alias `cprev` to be this exact command. The command should still be executed after setting the alias!

As we are commonly working multiple days on the same module, the alias should also get an entry in the `~/.bashrc` file (this is the main 'feature', so whenever they close the bash, they dont need to put in the whole command on reentering)

Now there are many posts about `history`and how to look up which commands where run last, etc., but I could not find out how to sort of 'concatenate' all the information to result in what I need.

I was thinking creating an alias for `grunt`.

Something like

```
alias grunt='~/myScriptForAliasHistory.sh;grunt $1';
```

would that be suitable?

**Edit**

to make this more clear:

The original command is

```
grunt compileModule:[name]
```

and it should be working like this after the modification.

It should only do an **additional step**, so you can call **the same function** as

```
cprev
```

as well (with the same parameters)

The workflow could look like this:

1. Developer starts working on a new module. In order to compile it, he writes `grunt compileModule:[name]`.
2. The same developer needs to restart his bash/pc/console. Now he does not want to write the whole command again, but wants to only type `cprev` (which then executes `grunt compileModule:[name]`)
3. The next day he starts working on module `[anothername]`, so he executes `grunt compileModule:[anothername]`
4. If he now restarts, the command `cprev` will execute `grunt compileModule:[anothername]`

In other words: 
Whenever `grunt compileModule` is called, it should overwrite the alias `cprev` with its own current call parameters.

Comment: What should be executed when you run your alias? Should it be a recursive call (i.e. should the alias invoke itself)?

Comment: You can't use positional parameters (e.g. `$1`) with an alias. You'd have to generate a function instead.

Comment: @Kusalananda I added an example workflow

Comment: @BLayer I know, it was just a thought of mine. a pseudo code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using history expansion with `!` will do this without an alias or function:

```
$ grunt compileModule:[something]

$ # other things

$ !grunt
```

The last `!grunt` will cause the shell to look up the last command in the command line history that starts with the string `grunt` and run that.

In `bash`:

> `!string`
>
> Refer to the most recent command preceding the current position
>                 in the history list starting with `string`.

If the shell has persistent history (usually enabled by setting `HISTFILE`), then this will also work across consecutive shell sessions, and depending on the shell, it may even work in concurrent sessions.